# Add a large fixed text in powerbuilder data window. How can do it ..?

Tags: powerbuilder

I want to add a large fixed text in powerbuilder data window report. How could I make it and which control should I use ...?

Thanks in advance
Ahammad Fekri

Comment: Please define what you mean a large fixed text. Is it 512 or 512M charecters ?

Answer (score 0):

The main ways to put text in a report are:

- Text control - Use for headers, labels, and other text that doesn't change on each row.
- Edit control - Use for text that needs to be different on each row. This uses a dummy column in the data source. Your program has to set the values in each row.
- Computed field - Use to display information that is calculated from
  other data in the DataWindow.
- Picture control - You would make a graphic of your text
  and display it as an image. You might use this for a fancy logo.

Comment: Be aware that the text controls are limited in characters (255?), and you can't mix font styles in a single control.

Answer (score 0):

Are you experiencing this problem with MySQL? The reason that I ask is that I've found that TEXT fields tend to crash PB unless you have the right DBPARM parameters set, MySQL uses a bitmask type setting and there are a few that are specific to PB in making the TEXT columns work.

I WISH that I had documented how I fixed this problem, but it was a connection parameter. If you get it right you can make the text work fine. If not MySQL then disregard.

You'd use a datawindow control most likely with a text field (wrap the text, etc.) or a rich text control maybe. The standard text controls work just fine.

Answer (score -1):

Forget the MLE control, I declared a textfield in the sql instead, it work so mutch better: in the select add a column like this: cast('' as char(3000)), or even bigger size, put this field in a computed column and in position tab check autosize height and if you want it: slide up directly above.
As for the values 
I got the values into a commaseparated list like this:
select list(distinct yourcolumn) into :ls_tmp from //etc..
The trick was to put in a space after each comma, the linebreaks works since the space triggers the linebreak to work properly. I used PFC and n_cst_string.of_globalreplace for this, you may find some useful replace code for this on the internet if you dont use PFC.
This worked perfect in my report.

Regards
Brage

---

I guess you already solved this, but for the record I did find a bit of a small workaround "hack".

I'm fooling the dwo with a floating powerbuilder object multiline edit, saving & updating its values to the datawindow edit at every rowchange. Its a drag, but it beats the 255 editing char limit. Im now able to copy & paste or write huge chunks of text as I please into the mle and save it to the db through the edit of the dwo. Im not sure this fix would work in any given situation though.

Something Id wish the Novalys of Appeon guys could fix in the dwo for future PB versions.